# Discrete, independent random variables with same distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be discrete, independent random variables with that have same distribution. Let $N$ be such number $n$, where first holds $X_n > X_1$. Does $N$ have $E(N)$?

Comment: first of all I want to find $Pr(N=n)$. It seems natural to me that satisfies geometric distribution $Pr(N=n)= p(1-p)^{n-1}$, where $p$ represents the probability that $X_n > X_1$, but the solution that I have says that $ Pr(N>n) = \dfrac {1}{n}$.

Where am I wrong with the reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming continuous random variables $X_i$ (i.e. a zero probability of ties):
$$\Pr(N=n) = \Pr(N=n | N \not \lt n)\Pr(N \not \lt n) = \frac{1}{n}(1- \Pr(N \le n-1)) $$

This is satisfied by $\Pr(N=n) = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ and $\Pr(N\le n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$, i.e. $\Pr(N\gt n)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ge 2$ and is easily checked by induction.

The expectation of $N$ is $$E[N] = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n \Pr(N=n) =  \sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{(n-1)}$$ which is infinite as a harmonic series.

Your error is to assume that $\Pr(N=n | N \not \lt n)$ is a constant $p$ rather than a decreasing function of $n$.  The probability that the $n$th value is bigger than all the previous values tends to fall as the number of previous terms increases.

For discrete random variables $X_i$, the calculation is distribution specific and harder, because of the possibility of ties.  Indeed, if $X_1$ can take the maximum value with positive probability, $N$ might then be infinite and so its expectation would be too.